# How do you attach eclipse plugin development library sources to a project?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, open-source

I am new to eclipse plugin development.

How can I get the source code for all eclipse plugin development libraries? Without the source code, it is hard to debug calls or look into the implementation.

Comment: I have the same question. I did not understand why this question is closed. Also, I don't understand how one could ask the question more accurately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most plugins, it is enough to use the context menu *Import -> As Binary plugin* in the Plugins view of the Plugin Development Perspective. If you need this for more than one plugin, you can do it [using a wizard and multi selection](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#importplugins).

If you are new to Eclipse plugin development, it will be very helpful to read more tutorials on the linked page, as it has many pointers.

Answer (score 9):

I refuse to download sources myself and attach them unless necessary. Eclipse does allow you to do this as it's shipped, the steps aren't too intuitive.

- Help > Install new Software
- Work with 'The Eclipse Project Updates' (not the main site!)
- Install the following items

  - Eclipse RCP Plug-in Developer Resources
  - Eclipse PDE Plug-in Developer Resources
  - Eclipse Platform Plug-in Developer Resources
  - Equinox p2 Core Function Source
  - Eclipse JDT Plug-in Developer Resources

This might not be a comprehensive list but it's a work in progress for me. I'll try to keep this list updated every time I find something new because StackOverflow has way better SEO than [my blog post](http://karunab.com/2013/10/08/eclipse-plugin-development-attaching-sources/) :)

Comment: Thank you. I wasted too much time trying to find a way to add the source code

Answer (score 0):

The release "**juno**" seems to be the problem.

Using pre-release "**kepler**" 4.3M6 the source will be viewed without any problems.

Comment: I had this problem in Kepler (I needed to do what @JAnderton suggested) but in Juno it was working practically out of the box. Probably has to do with how your Eclipse is installed (via package management vs. tarball to directory)